# Correlate Sequences of Independent Events - Calculate Time Intersection

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, dax

We are building a PowerBI reporting solution and I (well Stack) solved [one problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413626/calculate-event-durations-to-only-part-within-sliced-period) and the business came up with a new reporting idea. Not sure of the best way to approach it as I know very little about PowerBI and the business seems to want quite complex reports.

We have two sequences of events from separate data sources. They both contain independent events occurring to vehicles. One describes what location a vehicle is within - the other describes incident events which have a reason code for the incident. The business wants to report on time spent in each location for each reason. Vehicles can change location totally independent of the incident events occurring - and events actually are datetime and occur at random points throughtout day. Each type of event has a startime/endtime and a vehicleID.

**Vehicle Location Events**

```
+------------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+----------------+
| LocationDetailID | VehicleID | LocationID |  StartDateTime  |  EndDateTime   |
+------------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+----------------+
|                1 |         1 |          1 |        2012-1-1 |      2016-1-1  |
|                2 |         1 |          2 |        2016-1-1 |      2016-4-1  |
|                3 |         1 |          1 |        2016-4-1 |      2016-11-1 |
|                4 |         2 |          1 |        2011-1-1 |      2016-11-1 |
+------------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+----------------+
```

**Vehicle Status Events**

```
+---------+---------------+-------------+-----------+--------------+
| EventID | StartDateTime | EndDateTime | VehicleID | ReasonCodeID |
+---------+---------------+-------------+-----------+--------------+
|       1 | 2012-1-1      | 2013-1-1    |         1 |            1 |
|       2 | 2013-1-1      | 2015-1-1    |         1 |            3 |
|       3 | 2015-1-1      | 2016-5-1    |         1 |            4 |
|       4 | 2016-5-1      | 2016-11-1   |         1 |            2 |
|       5 | 2015-9-1      | 2016-2-1    |         2 |            1 |
+---------+---------------+-------------+-----------+--------------+
```

Is there anyway I can correlate the two streams together and calculate total time per Vehicle per ReasonCode per location?  This would seem to require me to be able to relate the two events - so a change of location may occur part way through a given ReasonCode.

**Calculation Example ReasonCodeID 4**

- VehicleID 1 is in location ID 1 from 2012-1-1 to 2016-1-1 and
  2016-4-1 to 2016-11-1
- VehicleID 1 is in location ID 2 from 2016-1-1
  to 2016-4-1
- VehcileID 1 has ReasonCodeID 4 from 2015-1-1  to 
  2016-5-1

Therefore first Period in location 1 intersects with 365 days of ReasonCodeID 4 (2015-1-1 to 2016-1-1). 2nd period in location 1 intersects with 30 days (2016-4-1 to 2016-5-1).
In location 2 intersects with 91 days of ReasonCodeID 4(2016-1-1 to 2016-4-1

Desired output would be the below.

```
+-----------+--------------+------------+------------+
| VehicleID | ReasonCodeID | LocationID | Total Days |
+-----------+--------------+------------+------------+
|         1 |            1 |          1 |        366 |
|         1 |            3 |          1 |        730 |
|         1 |            4 |          1 |        395 |
|         1 |            4 |          2 |         91 |
|         1 |            2 |          1 |        184 |
|         2 |            1 |          1 |        154 |
+-----------+--------------+------------+------------+
```

I have created a SQL fiddle that shows the structure [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfa16)

Vehicles have related tables and I'm sure the business will want them grouped by vehicle class etc but if I can understand how to calculate the intersection points in this case that would give me the basis for rest of reporting.

Comment: can you show some sample data and the expected output in the question? fiddle's don't always work.

Comment: @vkp Have updated - let me know if there is anything else I can show that would help.

Comment: It is unclear to me why ReasonCodeID 4 spans to location 1 and location 2. Shouldn't it only in location 1 and the total days =  184 days? Could you explain better.

Comment: Transposition error. Am fixing it now

Comment: Updated calculation explanation for ReasonCodeID4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this solution requires a `CROSS JOIN` implementation. The relationship between both tables is `Many to Many` which implies the creation of a third table that bridges `LocationEvents` and `VehicleStatusEvents` tables so I think specifying the relationship in the expression could be easier.

I use a CROSS JOIN between both tables, then filter the results only to get those rows which VehicleID columns are the same in both tables. I am also filtering the rows that VehicleStatusEvents range dates intersects LocationEvents range dates.

Once the filtering is done I am adding a column to calculate the count of days between each intersection. Finally, the measure sums up the days for each VehicleID, ReasonCodeID and LocationID.

In order to implement the CROSS JOIN you will have to rename the `VehicleID`, `StartDateTime` and `EndDateTime` on any of both tables. It is necessary for avoiding ambigous column names errors.

I rename the columns as follows:

`VehicleID` : `LocationVehicleID` and `StatusVehicleID` 
`StartDateTime` : `LocationStartDateTime` and `StatusStartDateTime` 
`EndDateTime` : `LocationEndDateTime` and `StatusEndDateTime`

After this you can use CROSSJOIN in the `Total Days` measure:

```
Total Days =
SUMX (
    FILTER (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            FILTER (
                CROSSJOIN ( LocationEvents, VehicleStatusEvents ),
                LocationEvents[LocationVehicleID] = VehicleStatusEvents[StatusVehicleID]
                    && LocationEvents[LocationStartDateTime] <= VehicleStatusEvents[StatusEndDateTime]
                    && LocationEvents[LocationEndDateTime] >= VehicleStatusEvents[StatusStartDateTime]
            ),
            "CountOfDays", IF (
                [LocationStartDateTime] <= [StatusStartDateTime]
                    && [LocationEndDateTime] >= [StatusEndDateTime],
                DATEDIFF ( [StatusStartDateTime], [StatusEndDateTime], DAY ),
                IF (
                    [LocationStartDateTime] > [StatusStartDateTime]
                        && [LocationEndDateTime] >= [StatusEndDateTime],
                    DATEDIFF ( [LocationStartDateTime], [StatusEndDateTime], DAY ),
                    IF (
                        [LocationStartDateTime] <= [StatusStartDateTime]
                            && [LocationEndDateTime] <= [StatusEndDateTime],
                        DATEDIFF ( [StatusStartDateTime], [LocationEndDateTime], DAY ),
                        IF (
                            [LocationStartDateTime] >= [StatusStartDateTime]
                                && [LocationEndDateTime] <= [StatusEndDateTime],
                            DATEDIFF ( [LocationStartDateTime], [LocationEndDateTime], DAY ),
                            BLANK ()
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        LocationEvents[LocationID] = [LocationID]
            && VehicleStatusEvents[ReasonCodeID] = [ReasonCodeID]
    ),
    [CountOfDays]
)
```

Then in Power BI you can build a matrix (or any other visualization) using this measure:

[image]

If you don't understand completely the measure expression, here is the T-SQL translation:

```
SELECT
    dt.VehicleID,
    dt.ReasonCodeID,
    dt.LocationID,
    SUM(dt.Diff) [Total Days]
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN a.StartDateTime <= b.StartDateTime AND a.EndDateTime >= b.EndDateTime  -- Inside range
               THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, b.StartDateTime, b.EndDateTime)
            WHEN a.StartDateTime > b.StartDateTime AND a.EndDateTime >= b.EndDateTime  -- |-----|*****|....|
               THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, a.StartDateTime, b.EndDateTime)
            WHEN a.StartDateTime <= b.StartDateTime AND a.EndDateTime <= b.EndDateTime  -- |...|****|-----|
               THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, b.StartDateTime, a.EndDateTime)
            WHEN a.StartDateTime >= b.StartDateTime AND a.EndDateTime <= b.EndDateTime  -- |---|****|-----
               THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, a.StartDateTime, a.EndDateTime)
        END Diff,
        a.VehicleID,
        b.ReasonCodeID,
        a.LocationID --a.StartDateTime, a.EndDateTime, b.StartDateTime, b.EndDateTime
    FROM LocationEvents a
        CROSS JOIN VehicleStatusEvents b
    WHERE a.VehicleID = b.VehicleID
        AND 
        (
            (a.StartDateTime <= b.EndDateTime)
                AND (a.EndDateTime >= b.StartDateTime)
        )
) dt
GROUP BY dt.VehicleID,
         dt.ReasonCodeID,
         dt.LocationID
```

Note in T-SQL you could use an `INNER JOIN` operator too.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Looks awesome - I will implement later and let you know. Really appreciate that.

Comment: I'm all but certain this code solves it. However I have been swamped with pressing client issues. I should get a chance to test tomorrow. I assume it works and I will issue you a bounty and accept answer. Sorry for delay in testing - it is really going to solve a reporting issue so massively appreciate the answer

Comment: Works perfectly I will award the answer the bounty once period allows. Do you think it is is it going to be hard to figure out the time per location per vehicle where there is no current corresponding event?

Comment: @GraemeMiller, I am glad it worked for you. I am unsure if you can manually award the bounty to a pre existing answer otherwise the bounty will be awarded to the highest voted answer, i.e that SQL answer posted after you opened the bounty. Regarding to the time per location and per vehicle I think it should be very similar to the answer I posted but looking for the locations ranges which don't intersect with status events ranges. If you post a question including more details and sample data I could give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

```
select      coalesce(l.VehicleID,s.VehicleID)   as VehicleID
           ,s.ReasonCodeID
           ,l.LocationID

           ,sum
            (
                datediff
                (
                    day
                   ,case when s.StartDateTime > l.StartDateTime then s.StartDateTime else l.StartDateTime end
                   ,case when s.EndDateTime   < l.EndDateTime   then s.EndDateTime   else l.EndDateTime   end
                )
            )   as TotalDays

from                    VehicleLocationEvents   as l

            full join   VehicleStatusEvents     as s

            on          s.VehicleID =
                        l.VehicleID

                    and case when s.StartDateTime > l.StartDateTime then s.StartDateTime else l.StartDateTime end   <=
                        case when s.EndDateTime   < l.EndDateTime   then s.EndDateTime   else l.EndDateTime   end   

group by    coalesce(l.VehicleID,s.VehicleID)
           ,s.ReasonCodeID
           ,l.LocationID
```

or

```
select      VehicleID
           ,ReasonCodeID
           ,LocationID
           ,sum (datediff (day,max_StartDateTime,min_EndDateTime))  as TotalDays

from       (select      coalesce(l.VehicleID,s.VehicleID)   as VehicleID
                       ,s.ReasonCodeID
                       ,l.LocationID

                       ,case when s.StartDateTime > l.StartDateTime then s.StartDateTime else l.StartDateTime end   as max_StartDateTime
                       ,case when s.EndDateTime   < l.EndDateTime   then s.EndDateTime   else l.EndDateTime   end   as min_EndDateTime

            from                    VehicleLocationEvents   as l

                        full join   VehicleStatusEvents     as s

                        on          s.VehicleID =
                                    l.VehicleID
            ) ls

where       max_StartDateTime <= min_EndDateTime

group by    VehicleID
           ,ReasonCodeID
           ,LocationID
```